# Android - Repeat method itself using spesific or dynamic time(in Millisecond)

Tags: java, android, repeat

I want to repeat method called `getMySchedule`, this method is in service, method `getMySchedule` will set `long timeRemaining;` in millisecond.
this is my short Code :

```
public class MyService extends Service{
   long timeRemaining;

   public void onCreate(){
       getMySchedule();
   }
   public void onBind(){
       return null
   }
   public void getMySchedule(){
      timeRemaining = timeFromSchedule; //this timeFromSchedule is from my Schedule
   }

}
```

now how to repeat this `getMySchedule` method it self, using `timeRemaining`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
public void getMySchedule(){
      timeRemaining = timeFromSchedule; //this timeFromSchedule is from my Schedule
      if(timeRemaining > 0){
          getMySchedule();
      }
   }
```

I'm hoping `getMySchedule` actually does other things or there is no point to this.